# apply XPath to a node, not to a whole document

Tags: r, xpath

in the `XML` package, there are functions like `getNodeSet(doc, path, ...)` and `xpathApply(doc, path, ...)` that allow to apply specific xpath to a XML document. What if I want to apply xpath to a node? For example:

```
myMatches <- getNodeSet(doc, '/html/body/table/tr') # list of nodes
myNode1 <- myMatches[[1]] # I want to work further only within this node 
mySubMatches <- getNodeSet(myNode1, '/tr/td') # this tries to look in the whole doc instead of just myNode1
```

Comment: thanks! seems I forgot the very basics of xpath syntax, shame on me. Could you paste your comment to the answer so that I can accept it as a solution?

Comment: P.S. I almost always provide an MRE, but here I thought the question was really obvious. If you think it's really necessary here, I will of course add it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slash at the start of you xpath means to start at the root. Try leaving off the leading slash to search that node. Try

```
mySubMatches <- getNodeSet(myNode1, 'tr/td')
```